# In Needham Schroeder key distribution what happens if responder's part is not encrypted in step 2 with Kbs but encrypted instead by Kab in step 3

Tags: key-distribution, needham-schroeder

The Needham-Schroeder protocol is:

1 A→S:A,B,Na

2 S→A:{Na,B,Kab,{Kab,A}Kbs}Kas

3 A→B:{Kab,A}Kbs

4 B→A:{Nb}Kab

5 A→B:{Nb−1}Kab

Here Na and Nb are nonces.

Kab is the key between a and b

Kas is the key between A and KDC

Kbs is the key between B and KDC

My Question: In step 2 if we don't encrypt with Kbs & in step 3 we encrypt

using Kab instead of Kbs what will happen? Following are the changes:

2 S→A:{Na,B,Kab,{Kab,A}}Kas

3 A→B:{Kab,A}Kab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kab is session key, which generated by KDC and must be new every time. So the most simple answer is: Bob could not to decrypt {Kab,A}Kab, because he does not know Kab before step 3.